# SOAP API .NET UpdateAdd/AddOnly to New List

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I am using the SOAP API for C# and I need to add subscribers to a new list.  If they already exist in that list, I would like to send them to a thank you page that says they already signed up.

If I use UpdateAdd I cant determine if they are already on the list to send to the already enrolled page.  If I use AddOnly and they are a subscriber in exact target in a different list, it will not add them to the new list.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the SaveAction within the Options, use the Action property at the List level to "create".  If they already exist, an error will be returned indicating they can't be created on the list. Example SOAP:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <Header>
      <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <UsernameToken>
            <Username>XXXXX</Username>
            <Password>XXXXX</Password>
         </UsernameToken>
      </Security>
   </Header>
   <Body>
      <UpdateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Objects xsi:type="Subscriber">
            <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
            <EmailAddress>example@example.com</EmailAddress>
            <Lists>
               <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
               <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
               <ID>123456</ID>
               <Status>Active</Status>
               <Action>create</Action>
            </Lists>
         </Objects>
      </UpdateRequest>
   </Body>
</Envelope>
```